# Flume Source for watching growing local file

Tags: flume

Which Flume Source suits better for watching growing local file (e.g., a log file)?

[Spooling Directory Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source) isn't suitable because it looks only new files and doesn't allow changes in exists files.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to use tail on that file in question using the Exec source.

Something like this:

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.type = exec
a1.sources.r1.command = tail -F /var/log/secure
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
```

Please note that this isn't the most reliable way, see also the warning in the documentation (https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#exec-source)